# Qt dynamic properties not set when in if statement

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm facing a strange issue in my Qt application... I have a Widget inheriting `QLabel` with the following stylesheet:

```
QLabel { padding: 10px ; }
QLabel[current-player=true] { background: blue ; }
QLabel:disabled { background: #eee ; }
```

And a method:

```
void MyWidget::updateInformation () {
    this->setEnabled (m_player->isEnable ());
    if (m_player->isCurrentPlayer ()) {
        qDebug () << "Setting current player to true: " << PlayerInfo::toString (m_player->player ()) ;
        this->setProperty ("current-player", true);
    }
    // this->setProperty ("current-player", true);
    qDebug () << "Property current player: " << this->property ("current-player") ;
}
```

As you can see, I want to set the background of my widget to blue when the `current-player` property is true, so I have the conditions `m_player->isCurrentPlayer()`.

I have a line commented, which was used to test if the property worked, and it did. When I uncomment the line, the background becomes blue.

What is strange is that my debug output is (when the line is commented):

```
Setting current player to true:  "Player1" 
Property current player: QVariant(bool, true) 
Setting current player to true:  "Player1"
Property current player:  QVariant(bool, true)
```

As you can see, the execution goes inside the if statement because I see the `Setting current player...` output, and the `current-player` property is true, **but the background stay white**...

I don't understand my the code works when I set the property all the time and doesn't work if I set the property in a if statement which is taken.

If anyone as an idea, it'll help me a lot!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's OK. Stylesheets are not recomputed when you change **custom** properties. Because of performance issues.

Solution: Call `polish()` and `unpolish()` to a widget with stylesheet.

P.S. I want to note, that usage of custom properties for such style customization is bad practice, because in case of complex styles it will cause UI lags.

Comment: I though the stylesheet was store in the QLabel, isn't it? But in this case, why the `QLabel:disabled` works? I can't try `polish` and `unpolish` right now, I'll check it and tell you if it worked.

Comment: It works, because 'QLabel:disabled' is not **custom** property. It's built-in QSS.

Comment: Thx, it worked! What should I do instead of using a custom property to add conditional style on a `QLabel`?

Comment: Do not use stylesheets at all ;). It is possible to set basic html text to label - you may use it - https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html. Something like `lb->setText( "<style color='red'>redlight</style>" );` P.S... check out qml - it provides much more customization abilities

Comment: I can't use inline `style` because what I really want to set is the left border of the `QLabel` (I can put the whole content in a style bloc but is it better ?). I'll have a look at QML, thx for your help!

Comment: You should take a final decision by yourself. Good solution - is working solution.